# In $\mathbb{Z}$, let m~n iff m-n is a multiple of 10.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> Prove that each of the following is an equivalence relation on the indicated set. Then describe the partition associated with that equivalence relation.
>
> In $\mathbb{Z}$, let m~n iff m-n is a multiple of 10.

So to show this equivalence relation, we need reflexive, symmetric and transitivity.

**Reflexive:** for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, then m~m holds since m-m=0 which is a multiple of 10.

**Symmetric:** for $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then if m~n then n~m must hold. since m-n is a multiple of 10 then n-m is also a multiple of 10.

**Transitivity** for $m,n,o \in \mathbb{Z}$ then if m~n and n~o is a multiple of 10, then m~o must hold. Therefore, if m-n and n-o is a multiple of 10, then m-o is also a multiple of 10.

The way I've been proving this is by actually using numbers but how can I actually prove equivalence relation so it covers all the integers. In other words, I feel like my work needs more details.

Comment: The sketch is good, but the proofs are not rigorous.  For example, for symmetric, you should let $m-n=x$ which is a multiple of $10$, so $x=10y$ for some integer $y$.  Then $n-m=-x=10(-y)$, which is also a multiple of $10$.

Comment: Great! This was helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your proofs are capturing the idea - which is a good position to start from - and agree that maybe a little more rigor could be desired. I think you would benefit from applying the definition:

> An integer $x$ is a multiple of $10$ is $x=10\cdot y$ for some integer $y$.

Or whatever definition you are using. For instance, in your proof of transitivity, which is by far the least spelled out, you might note that $m\sim n$ and $n\sim o$ implies that $m-n=10y_1$ and $n-o=10y_2$ for integers $y_1$ and $y_2$. Then $$m-o=(m-n)+(n-o)=10y_1+10y_2=10(y_1+y_2)$$ implying that $m-o$ is a multiple of ten. You can apply this to every proof - the point being to replace "is a multiple of 10", every time, with an appeal to the definition of that term - and in this case, it should always be possible to always demonstrate that things are multiples of $10$ by writing them as a product of an integer with $10$.

Comment: The definition helped a lot. Also, I just want to clarify since the question ask let m~n iff m-n is a multiple of 10. Since it is an iff meaning I have to show both sides. However, my sketch of the proof only proves the part "Let m-n be a multiple of 10, then m~n" If so, then how would I go about proving the other part "Assume m~n, then m-n is a multiple of 10"

Comment: @mika You're given "$m-n$ is a multiple of ten iff $m\sim n$" - you're not trying to prove that, you're trying to prove that, given that definition, $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. So, for instance, the statements you want to prove are: "$m\sim m$", "If $m\sim n$ then $n\sim m$" and "If $m\sim n$ and $n\sim o$, then $m\sim o$" - all of which only require a proof in one direction.

Comment: Thanks for the help and for clarifying!